# What feature toggle frameworks are available out there?

Tags: feature-flags, feature-toggles

Question inspired by [How to persuade developers to start using feature flag toggles?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-persuade-developers-to-start-using-feature-flag-toggles/343#343)

> - Find a feature toggle framework. Management/the business may be more amenable to trying something supported by a common system

and this comment on it:

> +1 for the framework bit. I've seen too many people roll their own
>   feature toggles and it's always nasty, nasty code. – Jduv 4 hours ago

So which are those feature toggle frameworks?

Pointers to the official framework sites are mandatory, but also at least some quotes from the site with a short description and maybe a summary of its features to not make them link-only answers.

Comments about the personal experiences in using the frameworks are welcome.

Comment: Can you provide some criteria to prevent this from being an endless list which becomes out of date quickly?

Comment: Well, I would write this as a CW post titled: "List of know feature toogle frameworks". Where everyone can modify it to add something to the list. Having it in the form of Q/A is not the good format IMHO.

Comment: @Tensibai: I don't intend the question itself from becoming the list end be endlessly edited for every update, I'd like to see the answers (community wikis or not) be items in the list, so that they can be individually updated, voted up/down or commented upon.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Q/A are not forums to react on every answer and write another answer addressing it. The format is not adapted for this as the sorting can be done by votes/activity/age. but the accepted one will end up at top whatever happens and default view is by votes which makes it horrible for a discussion like thing.

Comment: What I mean is that the site is not suited for every question. Some just doesn't fit.